# How to Focus on textinput field in alert combined with modaldialog in R?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, bootstrap-modal, sweetalert

I am building a `Shiny` `app` in which a user can open a `modalDialog` by clicking on points in a plot. The `modalDialog` contains a plot of the raw data behind the point clicked. The user is presented an `actionButton` linked to code to save the detailed plot in the `modalDialog` with a `sweetalert` `swal` message with an `inputfield`.
The problem is that `bootstrap` forces focus on the `modalDialog`, causing the inputfield to be blocked from use for typing.

I have seen some `javascipt` online that should overwrite the enforcefocus, but I am unable to make this work in `R`

The dummy code below has the same structure as my main app, and I reduced it as far as possible (might have left a few unneeded `libraries`, but they are all used in my `app`, and should not cause problems. All `packages` are the most recent versions.

The possible solutions use this code:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
```

or from bootstrap 4

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
```

found here: [link1](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/374) and here: [link2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19850)

Or a more complicated `javascipt` approach can be found here: [link3](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/412)

How to make the `app` focus on the `input` field, and 2nd, return focus to the `modalDialog` after `sweetalert` is closed?

thank you for any help!

APP:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)
  library(shinyBS)
  library(sweetalertR)
  library(shinyjqui)

  # ui section --------------------------------------------------------------


  jscode <- "
  shinyjs.swalsavepulse = function(params) { 
  var defaultParams = {
  title: null,
  text : null
  };
  params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
  swal({title : params.title, text : params.text,  
  type: 'input',
  inputType : 'text',
  html: true,
  showCancelButton : false,
  showConfirmButton : true,
  closeOnConfirm: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#339FFF',
  allowOutsideClick: true   },
  evalFunction = function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm === true) {
  var val1= 1;
  Shiny.onInputChange('pulsefilename', [val1, Math.random()]);}
  }); 
  };"


  ui <- fluidPage( 
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),     ### code for the sweetalerts
      shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jscode),  ### code for the sweetalerts

      tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.min.js"),   ### code for the sweetalerts
        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css",                                                  ### code for the sweetalerts
                  href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.min.css")    ### code for the sweetalerts
      ),

      actionButton(inputId = "popup", label = "Popup")
      )



  # server section ----------------------------------------------------------

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$popup, {
    pulseModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {         
                modalDialog(
                title = HTML(paste('<span style="color:white; font-size: 16px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Pulse shape viewer<span>')),
                actionButton(inputId = "message", label = "message"),
                easyClose = TRUE,
                footer = NULL) }

    showModal(div(id= "modalPulse", pulseModal() ))

    jqui_draggable(selector = '.modal-content')
    })

    observeEvent(input$message, {
          shinyjs::js$swalsavepulse(title = '<span style="color:#339FFF; font-size: 30px">Save pulse shape<span>',
                                    text = "Enter file name.")
            })

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When you come up with a solution you end up using, you should post that solution as your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if you already fix the problem, but, here is my answer.

I had the same problem, that's because `tabindex="-1"` on Bootstrap modal.

How i fixed:

```
// call this before showing SweetAlert:
function fixBootstrapModal() {
  var modalNode = document.querySelector('.modal[tabindex="-1"]');
  if (!modalNode) return;

  modalNode.removeAttribute('tabindex');
  modalNode.classList.add('js-swal-fixed');
}

// call this before hiding SweetAlert (inside done callback):
function restoreBootstrapModal() {
  var modalNode = document.querySelector('.modal.js-swal-fixed');
  if (!modalNode) return;

  modalNode.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
  modalNode.classList.remove('js-swal-fixed');
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: This code doesn't work in R. I am looking for an answer that turns one of the suggested codes in my question, or this code from you into R working code

Comment: Guess you don't know how to adapt it Pinfildi?

Comment: I realized that even though your code is not R based, it does hold the trick to solve the issue in R. By creating my own version of the normal modalDialog function, but without the tabindex = '-1' it now works indeed! At the time I didn't think of actually rewriting functions of an existing package to achieve this. Sorry for the original downvote