# Changing css params of a dropdownButton from shinyWidgets

Tags: r, shiny

I have designed a simple dropdownButton from the shinyWidgets package. Somehow I am unable to change the css parameters of the widget.

```
dropdownButton( icon = icon('info'), size = 'sm', right = T, up = F, width = '400px',
              div('my text', style = 'font-size:10px'))
```

I have tried to follow the css adjustment of the link here [shinywidget dropdownButton CSS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921470/shinywidget-dropdownbutton-css-tag)

However this only changed the pop-up window's params.

I tried to inspect the element and find the css codes but in vain.

Ideally I need to change the size of the button, the background color and opacity.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps, referring to this SO link [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543809/764386), the 'status' argument lets you set custom class (see [this](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/dropdownButton.html)). In the tags$style you can choose background color using 'background-color' and opacity using 'opacity'. The 'size' arguments lets you choose size of the button.

```
dropdownButton(status = "dropdownbutton", icon = icon('info'), size = "lg", right = T, up = F, width = '400px',
                div('my text', style = 'font-size:10px')
               ),
tags$head(tags$style(
  "
  .btn-dropdownbutton{
                      background-color: #393D3F !important;
                      border: solid; border-radius: 4px; border-width: 1px; border-color:#339FFF;
                      color: #339FFF; text-align: center; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px;
                      opacity: 0.5 !important;
    }
  "
```

Comment: I am unable to change the size of the button + font size (if no icon). Some of the params such as width/height/padding seem not to be working.

Comment: Are you still using circular button?